# List adding with sum()

Tags: python

I have got a program and I am trying to add all the numbers in the list together using `sum` but I don't think the format can anyone help?

```
list1 = ['01', '05', '07', '08', '10']
str1 = ','.join(list1)
print(str1)

total =(sum(str1))
print (total)
```

Comment: Do you need to add all the list elements or you want to combine all the list elements together ?

Comment: you can simply convert each element to integer and do sum

Answer (score 2):

Go like this:

```
sum([int(i) for i in list1])
```

Where:

```
[int(i) for i in list1]
```

Converts your list to `int`, and `sum()` adds up those integers.

Another approach is using `map()`:

```
sum(map(int, list1))
```

This also converts list1 into `int` and sums up the contents.

Finally you can `reduce()` your list using the anonymous function `lambda` that adds up elements converted to `int`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write single line of pythonic code to sum a list.

```
 print(sum(int(i) for i in list1)) #python 3.x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just in one line

```
sum(map(int, list1))
```

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) - this will map every element of `list1` to `int`

Comment: what is the reason @MoinuddinQuadri ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Do :

```
sum([int(ele) for ele in list1])
```

Your list is a `list of strings`, so here we are converting each element to `int` and than taking `sum` of it.

```
In : list1 = ['01', '05', '07', '08', '10']
Out : 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sum a string and not a list of integer. You need to convert your list to a list of numbers and then you can sum then:

```
list1 = ['01', '05', '07', '08', '10']
str1 = ','.join(list1)
print(str1)
number_list=[int(i) for i in list1]

total =sum(number_list)
print(total)
```